# Showing two metric spaces are not bi-Lipschitz equivalent but are uniformly isomorphic

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

How would one go about generating examples of metric spaces that are uniformly isomorphic (i.e. there is a uniformly continuous bijection between them with uniformly continuous inverse), but also fail to be bi-Lipschitz equivalent (bi-Lipschitz equivalent meaning there is a Lipschitz bijection between them with a Lipschitz inverse)? Furthermore, how could this be shown from first principles i.e. definitions of Lipschitz and uniform continuity?

I can think of examples e.g. R,d and R,f(d) where d is the Euclidean norm and f is not Lipschitz (or its inverse is not Lipschitz). However, I struggle to find a way to prove these spaces are not bi-Lipschitz equivalent i.e. there is **no** Lipschitz bijection with a Lipschitz inverse between them.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the definition of "uniformly isomorphic" for metric spaces $X,Y$? It is a less common concept than others in your question, and I can only guess at what it means. Does it mean, for example, the existence of a uniformly continuous homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$ with uniformly continuous inverse $f^{-1} : Y \to X$?

Comment: Yes it does - I'll update that

Answer (score 2):

$(\Bbb R, d_1)$ and $(\Bbb R, d_2)$ are examples when $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\min(1, |x-y|)$. These are uniformly equivalent (they induce the same uniformity and topology on $\Bbb R$) but there is no constant $C>0$ so that $d_1(x,y) \le Cd_2(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: But do we know that there is no bijective Lipschitz map (with Lipschitz inverse) such that d1(x,y) <= d2(f(x),f(y))? I see that it doesn’t work for the identity map (as you have shown) but that doesn’t mean it can’t work for some other map

Comment: @leonard find one, I dare you.

Comment: That part is the bit I’m having trouble with, I don’t know how to go about proving it’s not possible